# how to get rid of compiler error: C# use of unassigned local variable?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, unassigned-variable

I have some questions why C# doesn't like the `coordinates[j]` part and what I can do about it.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\sp\Dropbox\ProjectEuler\102\p102_triangles.txt");
string[] coordinates_str;
double[] coordinates; //Contains the coordinates for each line A1(x,y), A2(x,y), A3(x,y)
long ln = lines.Length;
Console.WriteLine("Length: " + ln.ToString());
for (int i = 0; i < ln; i++)
{
    Console.Write(i);
    Console.Write(lines[i]);
    coordinates_str = lines[i].Split(',');
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        coordinates[j] = Convert.ToDouble(coordinates_str[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you haven't allocated any space in coordinates[]...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You assign values to elements of `coordinates` without actually allocating storage first

```
double[] coordinates = new double[6];
```

So far you have just said `coordinates` is a reference to an array of doubles, but you have not said how large that array is (you have not allocated any storage).

Comment: Actually, the original code doesn't even say that `coordinates` is an array of doubles, only that it is a reference to an array of doubles, but there is no array.